# Bash - Built a CSV File from TXT

Tags: bash, grep

I'm newbie in using bash and grep ... I am trying to output a CSV file from a TXT file that contains this lines:

**Input:**

```
1. Fisrt - Name: Joanna Last - Name: Yang
Place of birth: Paris Date of birth: 01/01/1972 Sex: F
Number: 0009876541234567
2. Fisrt - Name: Bob Last - Name: Lee
Place of birth: London Date of birth: 05/08/1969 Sex: M
Number: 0005671890765223
```

**Output:**

```
"Joanna","Yang","Paris","01/01/1972","F","0009876541234567"
"Bob","Lee","London","05/08/1969","M","0005671890765223"
```

Any suggestions would be appreciated!!!!

Comment: Your post was a bit malformed. I formatted it for you. Please make sure, that I did not introduce any errors, e.g. that the input and expected output are correct. Does the input really contain multiple fields per line?

Comment: too late for an edit: here is a start https://alvinalexander.com/unix/edu/examples/grep.shtml Generally you should look at this guide [how to ask good questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Using only one regex with grep won't be easy.
You can try with multiple regexs and concat the results.

For instance:
To get the **first names** you can use this regex : `"Fisrt - Name: ([a-zA-Z]+)"`.
Save this into a variable.

Next to get the **birth dates** you can use `"birth: ([0-9]+\/[0-9]+\/+[0-9]+)"`.
Save this into a variable.

Do it for each part and concatenate the results with a coma.

Its clearly not the best way but it's a start.
To help with regex you can use https://regex101.com/ .

Maybe try using the [sed command line](http://www.grymoire.com/Unix/Sed.html)

Answer (score 0):

If your file is nice and nice formatted, no regex are needed.
We can read three lines at a time and split them on spaces - we are interested in only specified fields. If you can "assert" that no fields from the file will have spaces (I think no valid human name has spaces in it... right?), you can just do this:

```
while
    IFS=' ' read -r _ _ _ _ name _ _ _ last &&
    IFS=' ' read -r _ _ _ birthplace _ _ _ birthdate _ sex &&
    IFS=' ' read -r _ number
do
    printf '"%s","%s","%s","%s","%s","%s"\n' \
        "$name" "$last" "$birthplace" "$birthdate" "$sex" "$number"
done <input
```

Live version available at [onlinedbg](http://tpcg.io/Fvxh9d).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Unfortunately the file is not formatted in a regular way: there may be empty lines between one block and the other, there are some lines to jump like "Street name:".

Comment: With street names this method would indeed pose a problem, as streets may have spaces.

Answer (score 0):

In one line:

```
~ $ cat yourfile.txt 
1. Fisrt - Name: Joanna Last - Name: Yang
Place of birth: Paris Date of birth: 01/01/1972 Sex: F
Number: 0009876541234567
2. Fisrt - Name: Bob Last - Name: Lee
Place of birth: London Date of birth: 05/08/1969 Sex: M
Number: 0005671890765223
~ $ sed -r "s/^.*Fisrt - Name: (.*) Last - Name: (.*)$/\1,\2;/g" yourfile.txt | sed -r "s/^Place of birth: (.*) Date of birth: (.*) Sex: (.*)$/\1,\2,\3;/g" | sed -r "s/^Number: (.*)$/\1/g" | sed -n 'H;${x;s/;\n/,/g;s/^,//;p;}' | tail -n +2 > yourfile.csv
~ $ cat yourfile.csv 
Joanna,Yang,Paris,01/01/1972,F,0009876541234567
Bob,Lee,London,05/08/1969,M,0005671890765223
~ $
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! It returns every line I would need divided on three lines ... however the file is not formatted regularly ... it can have lines to exclude ...

1. Fisrt - Name: Joanna Last - Name: Yang
Place of birth: Paris Date of birth: 01/01/1972 Sex: F
Number: 0009876541234567
Street Name: Main Street

2. Fisrt - Name: Bob Last - Name: Lee
Place of birth: London Date of birth: 05/08/1969 Sex: M
Number: 0005671890765223
Stree Name:


2. Fisrt - Name: Bob Last - Name: Lee
Place of birth: London Date of birth: 05/08/1969 Sex: M
Number: 0005671890765223
Stree Name:

Comment: Well, sorry, not sure why this is not working. I just updated the answer for improving completeness. As you can see, files .txt and .csv seem to be correct. Maybe that is something about sed version, just guessing.